# how to deploy angular2 app built using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created n new angular app using angular-cli.

I completed the app and preview it using ng-serve, it is working perfectly.

After that I used *ng build --prod*, that generates the 'dist' folder. When I put that folder in xampp to run, it is not working. I found that there is no *.js files, which should be in there after *.ts -> *.js conversion (i suppose).

I have attached the screenshot, in which on left side it is showing the src folder having all .ts files, On middle it is showing the 'dist' folder and browser screenshot.

Please guide me how can I generate fully working app from angular-cli, which I can run in my xampp server.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of angular-cli? Are you using --mobile and angular-universal?

Answer (score 50):

**method 1(popular one) :**
If you are using angular-cli, then

```
ng build --prod
```

will do the trick. Then you can copy everything from `.dist` folder to your server folder

**method 2 :**

you can use http-server to serve your app . To install http-server

```
npm install http-server -g
```

and after going to your project folder

```
http-server ./dist
```

it will serve all the files in your folder. you can check the terminal what ip-address and port you can use to access the application. Now open up your browser and type

```
ip-adress:port/index.html
```

Hope it will help you :)

**Bonus :**
If you want to deploy in heroku. Please go through this detailed tutorial
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352

Comment: works, but first with angular cli you must build your project using ng build

Comment: You can type http-server ./dist -o to open the application directly in browser.

Comment: Thanks,it's works me but when i refresh the page it's getting not found error

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Saravanan.  I'm able to run http-server from within the ./dist folder, but only the root path works.  http://localhost:3000 (in my case) loads the app.  But if the user has any route bookmarked, like http://localhost:3000/project/listing, it throws a 404.  There is no apparent redirect capability.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone looking for an answer for IIS hosting...

Build your project

```
ng build --prod
```

Copy all contents of the ./dist folder into the root folder of your website maintaining the folder structure within ./dist (ie - don't move anything around).  Using the Beta-18 version of the angular-cli all assets (images in my case) were copied to ./dist/assets during the build and were referenced correctly in their containing components.

Comment: So you deploy the .gz and .map files as well?

Comment: On IIS you don't have to deploy the .gz files, just [configure](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression) IIS to use dynamic compression, you can save a lot of bytes going over the wire.  The .map files are source maps. Think of them as the .pdb's of the javascript world, so yes, if you want to debug on the server you're deploying to.  Uglifying the JS makes debugging really hard (read:impossible) without them.

Comment: I followed the method deploy in Apache server. It worked but the page showed as broken when refreshing(Cntrl+R) sub pages. for example In my case the page will not work accessing directly http://example.com/question. Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have a few proxy settings in proxy.conf.js file. After running "ng build --aot --prod" I deployed the dist files as-is. The website is up and running but the pages that use the proxy settings are still using localhost. How do I setup the proxy settings in production?

Answer (score 9):

Check your index.html file and edit this line

```
<base href="/[your-project-folder-name]/dist/">
```

Your content should load properly. You can then load styles globally

You should set base href as recommended by Johan

```
ng build --prod --bh /[your-project-folder-name]/dist/
```

Comment: Don't edit index.html, use ng build/serve with the --bh parameter

Comment: Oh Yes thanks, I believe the base href is the solution to his question.
       ng build --prod --bh /[your-project-folder-name]/dist/

Comment: +1 but wanted to clarify that you dont need to include dist in terminal

 ng build --bh /mycoolapp/   <----- worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with Heroku:

1. Create a Heroku account and install the CLI
2. Move the `angular-cli` dep to the `dependencies` in `package.json` (so that it gets installed when you push to Heroku.
3. Add a `postinstall` script that will run `ng build` when the code gets pushed to Heroku. Also add a start command for a Node server that will be created in the following step. This will place the static files for the app in a `dist` directory on the server and start the app afterward.

```
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "start": "node server.js",
  "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
}
```

4. Create an Express server to serve the app.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

5. Create a Heroku remote and push to depoy the app.

```
heroku create
git add .
git commit -m "first deploy"
git push heroku master
```

Here's a quick [writeup](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352#.bqcp67vdl) I did that has more detail, including how to force requests to use HTTPS and how to handle `PathLocationStrategy` :)

Comment: I recommend this! Great way to see your App in a live environment in no time. For more details: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352

Comment: What if you were using Angular Universal with a node server in Typescript?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng build` with the `--bh` flag

**Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html:**

```
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build --bh /myUrl/
```

Comment: I build my application using this `ng build --base-href "/testapp/" --prod` How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version of the Angular-CLI (at the time of this reply its 1.0.0Beta-18)

The way this version works is it puts everything in bundle files and it calls them in the index.html file. After that you have to copy your assets over to the dist folder (for some reason it does not do that). Finally, double check your base href make sure its set to what it needs to be set to and then it should work. That's what worked for me and I've tested on both Apache and Node.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Angular-CLI 1.0.0-beta.32.3

in the root directory of your project run 
**npm install http-server -g**

after successful installation run 
**ng build --prod**

upon successful build run 
**http-server ./dist**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is working with Nginx, then here is the complete solution:

Suppose you want to deploy your angular app at HOST: `http://example.com` and PORT: `8080`
Note - HOST and PORT might be different in your case.

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.

1. Firstly, go to your angular repo (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld) path at your machine.
2. Then build /dist for your production server using the following command:

   `ng build --prod --base-href http://example.com:8080`
3. Now copy /dist (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld/dist) folder from your machine's angular repo to the remote machine where you want to host your production server.
4. Now login to your remote server and add following nginx server configuration.

   ```
   server {

       listen 8080;

       server_name http://example.com;

       root /path/to/your/dist/location;

       # eg. root /home/admin/helloWorld/dist

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

           # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

       }

   }
   ```
5. Now restart nginx.
6. That's it !! Now you can access your angular app at http://example.com:8080

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: How do I run two webapps in the same the server?

Comment: you can run 2 different web apps on the same server by running that web apps on different ports. Eg. One will run on http://example.com:8080 and another one on http://example.com:8081.

Comment: How should the server configuration be? My domain would like https:\\example.com\webpage1\<routes> and https:\\example.com\webpage2\<routes>

Answer (score 0):

http-server doesn't support client-side routing, so nothing other than your base URL is going to work. Instead, you can use [angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server):

```
npm install -g angular-http-server
ng build --prod
cd dist
angular-http-server
```

This should only be used to test the app **locally** before deploying it on a Web server. To learn how to actually deploy the app on a Web server, check out the [Angular.io article on deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), which discusses considerations to make when building for deployment and provides configurations for a variety of different Web servers commonly used in production.