# Run Angular + Node.js app in production mode Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

So I have an Angular and Node.js app that I'm hosting on Heroku. I want to be able to run this app on localhost for testing but also have it work on Heroku. So I decided to use an environment variable to define the URL of the app for API calls.

So in `environment.ts` I have

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiURL: 'https://localhost:8080/'
};
```

And in `environment.prod.ts` I have:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiURL: 'myHerokuURL'
};
```

So when I run on heroku I want the production URL to be used. How can I do this?

To run locally I do, `nodemon server.js` then `ng serve`.

However on Heroku I need to do something like `ng serve --env=prod` but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Why not just do `ng build --prod` and have heroku serve the bundles?

Comment: actually i think you should not run both client and api servers on production, may be it good for you to have a look here:https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352

Comment: Never use ng serve for production ! It's à dev server with no security testing. If you don't use Angular universal and you have API in your server.js : build it with ng build --prod and add Static server in your server.js

Answer (score 0):

These should help

#### Option 1

If you are using angular-cli, then

```
ng build --prod
```

will do the trick. Then you can copy everything from `.dist` folder to your server folder

#### Option 2

you can use http-server to serve your app . To install http-server

```
npm install http-server -g
```

and after going to your project folder

```
http-server ./dist
```

it will serve all the files in your folder. you can check the terminal what ip-address and port you can use to access the application. Now open up your browser and type

```
ip-adress:port/index.html
```

Source: [how to deploy angular2 app built using angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672777/how-to-deploy-angular2-app-built-using-angular-cli/37744792#37744792)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json add

```
 "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration=production"
```

instead of

```
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
```

This will trigger only one (production) build on heroku. If you leave your current setup you can see in your heroku app logs that you first build everything with --prod but then it just makes normal build.